# RESTFful/Resource Oriented Design

Tags: web-services, rest, resources

Suppose I have a three level hierarchy consisting of school, students, and classes.

If I expose student as a resource, my question is whether I should always return the parent "school" and the children "classes" along with that student, or whether there should be parm that the user includes to indicate such.  Perhaps something like &deep=True?

Or on the other hand, if a user gets a student, and he wants the school, he has to do a GET on the school resource, and likewise if he wants all the classes that a student is taking, he has to do a GET on the classes resource?

I'm trying to keep the design somewhat open for the unknown future user, rather than coding just for what our current requirements demand.

Thanks,

Neal Walters

Comment: Others here have mentioned links; this is one of the constraints of REST i.e., hypertext as the engine of application state. Your representations should contain links to related resources e.g., a representation for a student should have a link to the resource of the school to which they belong. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717851/can-someone-explain-hypertext-as-engine-of-application-state-in-simple-terms for more on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should avoid thinking of classes as a sub-resource or attribute of a student. An academic class is more than just a time slot on a student's schedule; it has an instructor, a syllabus, etc., all of which may need to be encoded at some point.

As I see it, the following relations hold:

- schools have zero or more students
- schools have zero or more classes
- students have zero or more classes
- classes have zero or more students

(You could also trivially extend these with teachers/instructors, if your requirements included such information.)

In addition, each of the above resource types will have any number of attributes beyond the simple links between them.

Given that, I would think you'd want a URL structure something like the following:

- `http://example.com/lms/schools` => list of schools
- `http://example.com/lms/schools/{school}` => info about one school
- `http://example.com/lms/schools/{school}/students` => list of students
- `http://example.com/lms/schools/{school}/students/{student}` => info on one student
- `http://example.com/lms/schools/{school}/students/{student}/courses` => list of courses (as *links*, not full resources) student is enrolled in
- `http://example.com/lms/schools/{school}/courses` => list of courses
- `http://example.com/lms/schools/{school}/courses/{course}` => info on one course
- `http://example.com/lms/schools/{school}/courses/{course}/students` => list of students (as *links*, not full resources) enrolled in course

Comment: Thanks, I like your examples.  This is a hypothetical example, I was trying to think of a quick 3 level hierarchy. But if I know the student id (for example an Social Security Number), I might not know his school id. So when I retrieve the student, I might want his school data as well. 

In the cases where you have both school and student on the URL, would that imply that both would be returned in the resulting data-structure? 

Also find interesting your idea of returning a list of links.

Answer (score 5):

If you think about Resource design more in the way you think about UI design then the problem becomes easier.  There is no reason why you cannot return a subset of school information within the representation of the Student resource and also return a link to a complete representation of School resource in case the user wishes to see more.

I find it useful to think of a REST interface more like a user interface for machines instead of a data access layer.  With this mindset it is not a problem to duplicate information in different resource representations.

I know there are lots of people trying to treat REST like a DAL but they are the same people that get upset when they find out that you can't do transactions via a RESTful interface.

Put another way, design your API as you would design a website (but without any of the pretty stuff) and then build a client that can crawl the site for the information it needs.

Comment: Thanks.  Good point about transactions!  I spent a few hours this morning discussing with my colleague the pros/cons of making everything "atomic" (i.e. exposing a single database table as a separate resource) vs. combining "logical grouping" together into new super-resources.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that adding query parameters to optimize delivery is reasonable. I might make it even more generic and use `include=<relation>`. This can be extended for all types.  Note that
you can use multiple includes: `.../student/<id>?include=school&include=student` will assign the list `[school, student]` to the parameter `include`.  This will also allow a general pattern that may be possibly useful for the other resources as well.